# Configuring Evolution from .evolution and .local/share/evolution folders

Tags: evolution

I reinstalled (not upgraded) my system from Natty to Ocelot this morning.  I had backed up my home, including the ~/.* folders.

I have troubles getting Evolution to work.  Even though I restored the .evolution and .local/share/evolution folders, Evolution does not seem to realize that there are already a couple of gigabytes of files in 4 emails account already installed for it.  It keeps asking me to create accounts from scratch.

I realized later that I could have asked Evolution to build me a .tgz before reinstalling, but it's too late for that now.  I got used to the fact that copying files usually just work.

Does anyone know how I can make Evolution see what's there ?

Comment: Hi, Welcome To Ask Ubuntu, Please post it as an answer and mark it as answered :D

Answer (score 4):

There was one more directory to copy: .gconf/apps/evolution. This did the trick.